# How to click on a word and have a pop-up window come up in iOS

Tags: ios, popup, uitextfield

First off, thank you very much for taking some time to help me out.

I am rather new to iOS development and need some assistance on how to be able to enter text into a `UITextField` and then be able to tap a word and then have a pop-up screen come up. I am going to have the pop-up screen designate what highlight color the text is and I know how to go about doing that using

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *highlightedTextColor
```

I am not sure how to make each word register individually and then be able to tap it and have the pop-up come up. Thank you all for any help that you can aid me with.

Have a great day! :)

Comment: How are you displaying the 'words' that are able to be touched? In a list? A grid?

Comment: I would like the user to be able to type in their own text in a UITextField and then have them be able to click them. If there is a better way that you know of, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I mean... It sounds like you want to display multiple words at the same time, correct? How are you planning on laying all of the words out?

Comment: I would like the user to type the text in a UITextField and then have them be able to click the words that they typed and have the pop-up come up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough problem, but I think I have a solution that would accomplish what you need functionally, but I don't fully know your design constraints so your mileage may vary.

1. Create a UICollectionView with a layout that will flow across lines but always align items to the left. You can get a UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass to do this with not much work. This should be able to be styled to approximate the look of a UITextField to a degree.
2. Create a hidden UITextField.
3. When the user goes to enter input, make the hidden textField the first responder. This is just a container for their input.
4. As the user types, parse the text in the UITextField into word components by splitting the string on the ' ' character. Each word will be represented in the UICollectionView as one cell.
5. Implement the UICollectionViewDelegate method for cell selection. When the cell is selected, display your color picker pop up, set some color information to recreate the cell with the same color later on.

With this approach you won't have the typical editing tools like tapping words, moving your cursor, etc. You will have deletion, however.